# Questioning between django and two dates

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-views

I wrote an application with django. But I want to question between two dates. I wrote code as below but the results are empty

I want to list the records between the two dates I gave.
fields should be in the form dateTimeField

[image 1](https://ibb.co/Dp3qtCZ)
[image 2](https://ibb.co/kMgLF2t)

API: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/appointments/list?user=2&groupCode=1453&startDate=2020-04-17+10:00:00&endDate=2020-12-12+08:00:00

Model:

`

```
 user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=0, blank=False)
 startDate = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
 endDate = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
 groupCode = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
```

`

```
 class AppointmentsListAPIView(ListAPIView):
     serializer_class = AppointmentsCreateSerializer
     filter_backends = [django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend]
     filter_fields = ['customer', 'user', 'groupCode', 'startDate', 'endDate']

     def get_queryset(self):
         print(self.request.query_params.get('startDate'))

         queryset = Appointments.objects.filter(user=self.request.user,
                                           groupCode=self.request.query_params.get('groupCode'),
                                           startDate__gt=self.request.query_params.get('startDate'),
                                           endDate__lt=self.request.query_params.get('endDate'))
    return queryset
```

`

Error

RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField Appointments.endDate received a naive datetime (2020-12-12 08:00:00) while time zone support is active. RuntimeWarning)

RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField Appointments.startDate received a naive datetime (2020-04-17 10:00:00) while time zone support is active.
  RuntimeWarning)

Comment: This is only a warning, not an error (or you haven't added the error information)

Comment: the field I want to query is dateTimeField.
so there are no results

Comment: RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField Appointments.startDate received a naive datetime (2020-01-01 00:00:00) while time zone support is active.
  RuntimeWarning)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user needs to come from `self.request.user` not from `query_params`

Comment: I did as you said, but nothing changes again  [18/Apr/2020 15:56:24] "GET /api/appointments/list?user=2&groupCode=1453&startDate=2020-01-01+00:00:00&endDate=2020-12-12+00:00:00 HTTP/1.1" 500 171027

Comment: RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField Appointments.startDate received a naive datetime (2020-01-01 00:00:00) while time zone support is active.
  RuntimeWarning)
[18/Apr/2020 16:01:41] "GET /api/appointments/list?user=2&groupCode=1453&startDate=2020-01-01+00:00:00&endDate=2020-12-12+00:00:00 HTTP/1.1" 200 7701

Comment: Lack of results has nothing to do with warnings. You can create zone aware dates before running the queries to fix the warning.

Comment: It's really difficult to say what else could be going wrong. What is present in the DB. Can you print all Appointments queried from DB? Also, looks like the return queryset statement is outside get_queryset! is it just a paste error or your function is actually returning None for queryset?

Comment: Update your queryset to filter only on dates to narrow the issue - remove these 2 lines  user=self.request.user,
                                           groupCode=self.request.query_params.get('groupCode'),  What is the result of query after that?

Comment: yes, I removed it as you said but it turns blank
/api/appointments/list?startDate=2020-01-01+00:00&endDate=2020-12-12+00:00

Comment: Sure. Please paste actual code somewhere, There could be some small error related to an indentation that is to showing up after pasting here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211956/discussion-between-fatih-mzm-and-mahori).